# What is the difference between django-social-auth and python-social-auth?

Tags: django, django-socialauth, python-social-auth

I'm confused very much, because django-social-auth and python-social-auth seem to be the same, but they are not. In fact python-social-auth is based on django-social-auth.

Now I can't find any resource that compares those two by any means. I can't even find a statement in the python-social-auth docs why they made their own project instead of just working with django-social-auth.

For my project I need to settle on one of those two. Can you give me any help to make this choice?

Think you for your time.

Comment: How about helping instead of being rude? I already said I can't find it in their docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

django-social-auth has been deprecated in favor of python-social-auth. It even says this [in the django-social-auth README](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/blob/master/README.rst).

python-social-auth was built using django-social-auth as a foundation. The main advantage/difference is that it now supports multiple frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

the newest version is the python-social-auth, and django-socail-auth has been depricated.

python-social-auth is very modular library looking to provide the basics tools to implement social authentication / authorization in Python projects. For that reason, the project is split in smaller components that focus on providing a simpler functionality. Some components are:

```
social-auth-core Core library that the rest depends on, this contains the basic functionality to establish an authentication/authorization flow with the diferent supported providers.
social-auth-storage-sqlalchemy, social-auth-storage-peewee, social-auth-storage-mongoengine Different storage solutions that can be reused accross the supported frameworks or newer implementations.
social-auth-app-django, social-auth-app-django-mongoengine Django framework integration
social-auth-app-flask, social-auth-app-flask-sqlalchemy, social-auth-app-flask-mongoengine, social-auth-app-flask-peewee Flask framework integration
social-auth-app-pyramid Pyramid framework integration
social-auth-app-cherrypy Cherrypy framework integration
social-auth-app-tornado Tornado framework integration
social-auth-app-webpy Webpy framework integration
```